# What's algorithm of ordination the library Thrust (CUDA) uses?

Tags: sorting, cuda, thrust

What's algorithm of ordination the library Thrust (CUDA) uses? (i.e. quick sort, merge sort)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Thrust uses two sorting algorithms:

- Merge Sort
- Radix Sort

Which algorithm is used depends on the data type being sorted (Radix Sort is used for primitive types, Merge Sort for the rest).

Comment: hmm, all right. Thanks a lot :D 
I need research about Radix Sort, this is new to me.